# Perl -Open Source Explaination for Slic3r "honeycomb" pattern

Tags: perl

I have no knowledge of perl, and the open source code I'm looking at it still uses a small element of it. I'm trying to work out if there is anything significant with the words 'honeycomb'? Are they just checking if the variable pattern is equal to the string or am I missing anything?

```
 # prepare fillers
my $pattern = $self->object_config->support_material_pattern;
my @angles = ($self->object_config->support_material_angle);
if ($pattern eq 'rectilinear-grid') {
    $pattern = 'rectilinear';
    push @angles, $angles[0] + 90;
} elsif ($pattern eq 'pillars') {
    $pattern = 'honeycomb';
}
```

https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/blob/master/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to work out if there is anything significant with the words 'honeycomb'?

Nothing as far as the Perl here is concerned. It is just a string.

[Something else](https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/search?q=honeycomb&unscoped_q=honeycomb) will, presumably, read that variable.

> Are they just checking if the variable pattern is equal to the string

No. It is an assignment, not a comparison